# Web service stopped working after deploy

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, heroku, spring-boot

It works locally on localhost. 
Tried to deploy on Heroku and AWS. Doesn't work. But static resources are ok.
Response is 404.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class WebService implements WebServiceInterface{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(WebService.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping("/getcontent")
    public WebContent getContent(@RequestParam(value="id", defaultValue="summary") String id) {
        try {
            return new WebContent(id);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    } }
```

Comment: 404 means either web app not deployed or your calling the wrong URL. Any logs related to deployment may help in analyze.

Comment: There is insufficient evidence in your question for a diagnosis.

Comment: -------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.txt
-------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Aug/2015:21:18:35 +0000] "POST /getcontent HTTP/1.1" 404 1014

Comment: No errors on a deploy stage

Answer (score 0):

1. Locally I used

   mvn spring-boot:run

That's why I had no problem with my web service

2. For Heroku and AWS I deployed war package. It didn't work for my code.
   Only this initializer helped to solve my problem:

   ```
   public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(Application.class);
     }
   }
   ```